# performing outer addition with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am just getting started with python/numpy and I'm really not sure of the most efficient ways to go about things. I'm putting together a demo N-body simulator for some students, but for now, I am computing the force between particles by looping over the positions of those particles which is predictably as slow as molasses. Basically, given a vector `x[i]`, I would like to compute:

```
n[i] = sum from j = 0 to n-1, j != i of (x[i]-x[j])^-2,
```

using numpy functions rather than looping. If there is a way to perform outer addition/multiplication:

```
m[i,j] = x[i]-x[j],

m[i,j] = x[i]*x[j],
```

I could use that to do the computation.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

All universal functions that take two input arguments have an attribute `outer`:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.subtract.outer(x, x)
```

gives:

```
array([[ 0, -1, -2],
       [ 1,  0, -1],
       [ 2,  1,  0]])
```

and

```
np.multiply.outer(x, x)
```

results in:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: This is such a great feature! For those interested there's further reading on the [ufunc documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html#methods).

Comment: I'm curious to know if this `outer` operation has got a name in math (or if the name varies with the operator, like "outer product" for `multiply`).

Comment: maybe worth mentioning this is not limited to (x,x) but applies generally to (x,y) with x and y of any shape or length

Answer (score 24):

Many of numpy's basic operators such as `np.add`, `np.subtract`, `np.multiply` etc. are known as [universal functions (ufuncs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/ufuncs.html), and have (amongst other things) an [`.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) method:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(5)
c = np.add.outer(a, b)
print(repr(c))
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Another very powerful technique for doing this sort of thing is [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
print(repr(a[:, None] + b[None, :]))
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Indexing with `None` (or alternatively, with `np.newaxis`) inserts a new dimension, so `a[:, None]` has shape `(3, 1)` and `b[None, :]` has shape `(1, 5)`. Broadcasting "expands" the result along the singleton dimensions, so that it has shape `(3, 5)`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning broadcasting. a powerful feature, poorly understood, responsible for much good and evil in numpy-dependent code.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Numpy.outer vs. broadcasting; are these equivalent and calculated the same way with similar expected performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70370522/3904031)

Comment: @gansub *Thanks!* I always like to start my mornings with Python and coffee :-)