# Outer sum of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two arrays:

```py
# A
[[0 3]
 [2 3]
 [3 1]]

# B
[[2  0]
 [0 -1]
 [0  1]
 [1  0]]
```

The result should be the outer sum coordinate-wise:

```
[[2 3],[0 2],[0 4],[1 3]], # [0 3] + each element of B
[[4 3],[2 2],[2 4],[3 3]],
[[5 1],[3 0],[3 2],[4 1]]
```

I managed to solve it with loops, however, the vectorized implementation is needed to work with large matrices. I have approached this with [outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) sum, but without any success.

```
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        print(i+j)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [performing outer addition with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848599/performing-outer-addition-with-numpy)

Comment: Think - `a[:,None,:] + b` Or simply - `a[:,None] + b`.

Comment: @Divakar : Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Sheldore I have a good hunch, it's covered as a possible duplicate Q&A. The search on SO isn't really helping though.

Comment: @Divakar : Fair enough

Comment: @Divakar Thanks, that actually works. But I didn't get the logic, and what if the coordinates were three-dimensional?

Comment: @Moti By three-dimensional, do you mean three columns instead of two?

Comment: @Divakar Yeah, exactly. Sorry for the inconvenient term.

Comment: @ Moti Should work regardless. @Sheldore Couldn't locate one, not at least going through my earlier posted ones. Hence, posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply extend `a` to `3D` keeping the last axis aligned with the last one from `b` and add them up. This would leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution. To do the extension to higher dimensions, we can use `np.newaxis/None`.

Hence, simply do -

```
a[:,None,:] + b[:, :]
```

Skipping the redundant last axes specified with `:'s`, we would be left with -

```
a[:,None] + b
```

Schematically put -

```
a[:,None,:] :   m x 1 x n
b[:,:]      :       k x n
output      :   m x k x n
```

For large arrays, we can also leverage `numexpr` that makes uses of multi-cores. To do so, we need to port the earlier listed broadcasting method with few modifications, like so -

```
import numexpr as ne

ne.evaluate('a3D+b',{'a3D':a[:,None]})
```

Timings -

```
In [17]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.rand(1000,3)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(1000,3)

In [18]: %timeit a[:,None] + b
11 ms ± 92.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit ne.evaluate('a3D+b',{'a3D':a[:,None]})
4.1 ms ± 95.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```