# How to combine values with two matrices and add combinations?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays. I try to combine them and read the individual values from the matrix, each value with the first matrix with each value with the second matrix and store the result in a variable

```
import numpy as np
X=np.arange(0,3) 
Y=np.arange(0,3)
```

Here is an example of how it should be combined and added

```
X=0 + Y=0 = Z=0  
X=0 + Y=1 = Z=1  
X=0 + Y=2 = Z=2  
X=1 + Y=0 = Z=1 
X=1 + Y=1 = Z=2 
X=1 + Y=2 = Z=3  
X=2 + Y=0 = Z=2  
X=2 + Y=1 = Z=3  
X=2 + Y=2 = Z=4
```

I thought it would be possible via a combination number and function comb, but there it only works with one matrix.

Is there any way to do this? The nuts do not always have to be this size

Comment: how would this `Z` look like?

Comment: By combine, do you mean addition of the corresponding elements?

Comment: combining I think it will first take the first element from the first matrix and combine them with each element from the second matrix, ie 0 + 0. 0 + 1. 0 + 2. Then take the second element from the first matrix and combine them with the numbers in the second matrix, and thus 1 + 0,1 + 1 + 2 and so on to the end

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the "outer sum":

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> b = np.arange(3)
>>> np.add.outer(a, b)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Any NumPy [universal function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) (ufunc) has an outer version; see [`np.ufunc.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848599/performing-outer-addition-with-numpy).

If you want the output to be a 1D array, you can flatten it:

```py
>>> np.add.outer(a, b).flatten()
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
Z = np.matrix([[f(x,y) for y in Y] for x in X])
```

With this line of code, the coefficient (i,j) of matrix Z will be equal to Z_{i,j} = f ( X_i,Y_i ).

If f is simply the addition, the code becomes

```
Z = np.matrix([[x+y for y in Y] for x in X])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this operation by using meshgrid to get combinations and then sum them as follows:

```
import numpy as np

X=np.arange(0,3) 
Y=np.arange(0,3)

#get combination of X, Y
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(X, Y))
combinations = mesh.T.reshape(-1, 2)
sums = combinations.sum(axis=1)

print(combinations, sums)
```

Outputs:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]][0 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 4]
```