# How to calculate the outer sum (not product) between 2 (1D) vectors

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-einsum

It seems like [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) should do the trick, but I haven't been able to make it work.

An example:

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(2)

#that computes the outer product
res = np.einsum('i,j->ij',a,b)

#The resulting array I am looking for is:
out = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
#or its transpose.
```

I've been searching and all functions seem to point towards outer product, not outer sum. A `for` loop would do the job, but I'd like to have something a lot more efficient than that.

Does anyone know how to implement the outer sum using `np.einsum` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer sum:

```
res = np.add.outer(a, b)
```

Comment: Yes, after posting I found that function. In general, this answer explains better the property that general numpy functions have an outer property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848599/performing-outer-addition-with-numpy

Answer (score 2):

```
In [610]: a = np.arange(3)
     ...: b = np.arange(2)
     ...: 
In [611]: np.add.outer(a,b)
Out[611]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

By adding a dimension to `a` (3,1), we can use the addition operator.  Look up `broadcasting` for details.

```
In [612]: a[:,None]+b
Out[612]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```