# Numpy.outer vs. broadcasting; are these equivalent and calculated the same way with similar expected performance?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

[This answer to *performing outer addition with numpy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848814/3904031) discusses numpy's ufunc's "outer" and also numpy's broadcasting, and the examples there are summarized below.

In the case of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, is the calculation the same under the hood, or will there be differences in performance, especially when the array size gets large?

Minimal, 2D example from the linked answer:

```
import numpy as np

a, b = np.arange(3), np.arange(5)

print(np.add.outer(a, b))

print(a[:, None] + b)      # or a[:, np.newaxis] + b
```

both result in:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 6]]
```

Comment: have you done any of your own timings?

Comment: @hpaulj I have not asked about that. I've asked if they are calculated the same way and *should have similar expected* performance or not. If they end up being the same then there's no point in testing, and relying on testing alone could lead to surprises later in unusual cases not previously tested.

Comment: I'm afraid equality of performance is a necessary condition for two methods being calculated in the same way but not compulsory. At least, you have an easy way to reject your hypotesis.

Comment: `%timeit np.add.outer(a, b)`: 5.67 ms ± 276 µs; `%timeit a[:, None] + b`: 5.74 ms ± 274 µs where both `a` and `b` are `np.random.randint(100, size=1000)`

Comment: @mathfux there's also the possibility that they are *intended* to be the same (e.g. one calls the other) but the call was implemented incorrectly or sub-optimally. I'm primarily interested to know if these two are different animals existing separately from each other but should provide the same results, or if they're actually ultimately the same implementation.

Comment: @uhoh after comparing speed there is hardly a difference even when scaling up array sizes; although I'd usually suggest sticking to numpy to be consistent with the rest of the code, broadcasting does seem more appealing to me in this context at least. If there isn't a clear difference between the two in terms of computation time and expected output of the operations it would be more of a personal preference.

Comment: @mathfux I ran the same test before I initially commented, and after running the tests repeatedly the times were overlapping by enough of a margin that I don't think it's fair to suggest either one is faster than the other.

Comment: @OriYarden have multidimensional configurations been fully explored? Some axes are faster than others... cf. the 4D array in [Convolute a gaussian kernel with a large array of off-grid centroids without looping? (how to make "A Thousand (Gaussian) Points of Light" )](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/37791/17869) Sometimes I have 5 dimensions.

Comment: @uhoh made a great point! Broadcasting time was in microseconds (µs) while numpy clocked in the milliseconds (ms) when using numpy's 3D matrix instead of the arranged list. Broadcasting proves to be computationally more efficient! I just tested it.

Comment: It's easy to compare the 2 with 1d arrays.  But if `x,y` are both 2, `np.add.outer(x,y)` is equivalent to `x[:,:,None,None]+y`.  But more often when using broadcasting, we want something like `x[:,None,:]+y[None,:,:]` or some other combination of axes that can't be expressed with `outer`.  Personally I don't use `outer` very much, not even the simple `np.outer` version.  Broadcasting has much more expressive power.

Comment: @hpaulj Until today I only knew broadcasting, so I'm trying to understand if `.outer` is just legacy to be avoided or if there are some cases where it might be preferred. I just don't have the skill/background to look "under the hood" to see if it *at least potentially* has something unique and useful, or if I should just forget it as quickly as I learned about it :-)